# Durandal optimization with Gulp and Gulp-Durandal not working

Tags: requirejs, gulp, durandal, bundling-and-minification

We are building an application with Durandal which is quite big at the moment and we currently looking into bundling all JS files located in the App folder into a main-built.js file. Pretty basic and usual stuff I guess.

I'm using Gulp with the Gulp-Durandal extension. Here our gulpfile :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var durandal = require('gulp-durandal');

gulp.task('build-portal', function () {
    durandal({
        baseDir: 'app',
        main: 'main.js',
        output: 'main-built.js',
        almond: false,
        minify: false
    }).pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
});
```

And here's a snippet of our main.js file

```
require.config({
paths: {
    'text': '../Scripts/text',
    'durandal': '../Scripts/durandal',
    'plugins': '../Scripts/durandal/plugins',
    'transitions': '../Scripts/durandal/transitions'
},
shim: {
},
waitSeconds: 0
});

define('jquery', [], function () { return jQuery; });
define('knockout', [], function () { return ko; });
define('ga', function () { return ga; });

define(
    ["require", "exports", "durandal/app", "durandal/viewLocator", "durandal/system", "plugins/router", "services/logger", "modules/knockout.extensions", "modules/knockout.validation.custom"],
    function (require, exports, __app__, __viewLocator__, __system__, __router__, __logger__, __koExtensions__, __koValidationCustom__) {
        var app = __app__;
        var viewLocator = __viewLocator__;
        var system = __system__;
        var router = __router__;
```

As you can see in the gulpfile, we do not want to use Almond but RequireJs instead, for some reasons almond isn't workin with our project and anyhow, we prefer RequireJs whether its bigger than almond at the end. That's where it look to brake. Running the command to build the main-built.js file took sometime but at the end I get the file built with everything in it.

The problem is that when I try to load the application, it is stuck to the loading screen. It doesn't go any further and there's no errors at all in the browser console.

I created a new project on the side to test if our code was somewhat faulty and found that it might not. You can found that project here : 
https://github.com/maroy1986/DurandalGulpBundling

If I build that project with almond option to true, everything works fine but if I switch almound off to tell gulp to use RequireJs, I got the same behavior as our app. You got stuck at the loading screen, without any errors.

So here I am, I do read a lot on the subject but didn't found anything to solve this. Hope someone here already encounter these behavior and have a solution to share.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same requirement and issue. It seems require.js wasn't calling the main module which will startup the Durandal app, that's why it's stuck in the loading screen. I was able to resolve it by implicitly calling the main module:

```
gulp.task("durandal", function() {
    return durandal({
        baseDir: "app",
        main: "main.js",
        output: "main-built.js",
        almond: false,
        minify: true,
        rjsConfigAdapter: function(config) {
            //Tell requirejs to load the "main" module
            config.insertRequire = ["main"];
            return config;
        }
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});
```

Comment: This sounds promising, I'll have a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: @Marc-AndreR. Let me know if this worked out for you. I have exactly the same requirement (to use requirejs instead of almond) and had the same issue (durandal app not loading and stuck at loading view). After implicitly specifying to load the main module (main.js), it worked like it did when using almond. I could probably set-up a repo for this as this is probably a common issue people encounter when using requirejs and durandal.

Comment: Well, looks like you got it! It work. There's still some glitch thought in the application like things that didn't load but the app is globally working beside a few javascripts error I get. Looks like he can't find the "app" class since I use it to update page title with app.title = "whatever" on a router:navigationcomplete event. Tried to add it to the requirejs paths but that doesn't seems to help. If ever you had the same issue, maybe you'd like to share your solution :) Thanks!

Comment: @Marc-AndreR. Are you getting that issue with the project you linked to? I'll try out your project as well as a put up a sample project on GitHub. I'm trying to make BreezeJS work with Gulp-Durandal but it doesn't look like it plays well with RequireJS and Almond.

Comment: No this is not the project I linked here. This is in the real project, which is a way larger application. At the moment, nprogress didn't work and there's seems to be some routing issues.

Unfortunately, I didn't have assigned time to work on this, this way more a personal side project to improve our application. So I am working on it on loose time, which I don't have a lot.

But in case of any progress on this, I'll sure keep you post :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76182/discussion-between-marc-andre-r-and-cubski).

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded your project and tried building it with the latest versions of gulp and durandal. Initially it didn't build and gave me the following error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'normalize' of undefined
```

This is a problem with the text-plugin of rjs and you can solve this by adding the following to your gulp-file (next to the almond, minify, output... properties):

```
rjsConfigAdapter : function(rjsConfig){
            rjsConfig.deps = ['text'];
            return rjsConfig;
        }
```

Once I did that, the build finished and I could build with or without minify, almond and require and the application works fine.

Comment: I'll have a look at this tonight. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for your follow-up.  I was running into this problem because I was switching our project from using Weyland which was no longer working to using Gulp.  The problem was driving me nuts, but the lines above fixed the issue.